# Creating a new list by combining element of previous list in R

Tags: r

I have a list something like this:

```
    v = list(a1= 1, a2 = 2, b1 = 3, b2= 4, b3 = 5)
```

my desire result is creating a list something like this :

```
   v = list(a = c(1, 2), b = c(3, 4, 5))
```

But it should be mentioned that vector `v` is my exapmle, I can wrote the code for above example,  but my problem is that if each time the length of `ai` and `bi`is different, how can wrote a function to get my desire result in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
split(unlist(v), sub("\\d+$", "", names(v)))
# $a
# a1 a2 
#  1  2 
# 
# $b
# b1 b2 b3 
#  3  4  5
```

Comment: I do not need the names a1, a2, b1, b2, b3. How can I remove these names from result? I just need $a and $b.

Comment: I found how can I remove these names:split(unlist(v, use.names=FALSE), sub("\\d+$", "", names(v))). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a more clever way but here's one approach with regex:

```
starters <- letters[1:2]
v2 <- lapply(starters,  function(x) {
    unname(unlist(v[grepl(x, names(v))]))
})

names(v2) <- starters

## $a
## [1] 1 2
## 
## $b
## [1] 3 4 5
```